# how to display more options based on users selection

Tags: html, forms, list

i have a table. i have two options in a list. when the user clicks the second option some more rows/ data/new list should appear. how to do this?

```
<table width="1000" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>SIGNUP</td>
    <td>
    <select>
    <option>As teacher</option>
    <option>As student</option>
    </select>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input name="" type="text" size="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

if the user chooses "student" then some more parameterts should also be displayed in the form.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Write a Javascript handler for the selection event
- Step 2: Initiate an AJAX connection to retrieve the data for the
  second list based on the selection criteria in the first list.
  Alternately, you can retrieve this data at page load time and store
  it in a suitable data object, then access it at this time.
- Step 3: Create another HTML select control to contain the second data. This
  control can be created via HTML and initially hidden, or create in
  Javascript from scratch at the time of the event.
- Step 4: Populate the new second select control with the data retrieved in Step 2.

To successfully complete each of these steps, you will need to learn about Javascript event handlers, AJAX, and DOM manipulation. Consider using jQuery or another framework to simplify some of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with some form of Javascript (I'll use jQuery in my example because it is easier).

In order to show more options, they have to be shown/hidden on the `onchange` event, like so:

```
$("#op1").change(function(){
   
    $(".options2").fadeOut();
    $(".options3").fadeOut();
    
    if($(this).val()=="1")
    {
        $(".options2").fadeIn();
    }
    else if($(this).val()=="2")
    {
        $(".options3").fadeIn();
    }
    
});
```

In this example, `#op1` is the first select; `onchange` if it's value is 1, it will show `div.options2`, the container of another select; if it's value is 2, it will show `div.options3`, the container of a third select.

Both `options2` and `options3` can either be hard-coded into the page or be appended (using `.append()`) when necessary.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryhWE/)

---

### Note: You will need to import [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) for this to work.